.NET MAUI Android : Write to Folder Outside App Folder
In newer Android versions it is no longer possible to read/write files outside the applications hidden folder, unless the USER selects the folder.
Expecting our users to select a folder to write logs and archival data to is NOT a solution.  But this seems to be the only way to get read/write permissions outside the app folder in later Android versions (I think greater than 10).
I am very curious as to what others might be doing to solve this problem with the upgrade path.  Our app is not a "game", etc.: It is a complex industrial app that field engineers use every day. They sometimes run into problems which requires them to send us log files and other archived data from the app.  To date, they have been hooking up their devices to a laptop via USB and simply pull files from a folder on the emulated SDCARD. Works like a dream.
This is no longer possible.  And it is IMPOSSIBLE to expect our users to use something like ADB to shell into the file system, run-as a particular app, and navigate through the folder structure to pull log files, etc.
I am sure we are not alone in this problem.
What are other developers doing to solve the problems introduced by the straight jacket style "security" being imposed by new versions of Android?
Thanks,

da


"It is a complex industrial app that field engineers use every day" -- are you deploying this app on hardware that you control (i.e., it is your firmware)?

why don't you build the log submission process into the app?

I agree with @Jason, building the submission process into the app seems like a good approach - it also reduces the steps your users have to take to submit those logs. In case you need to support offline scenarios, you can then also add FileSaver functionality as a fallback to export the logs to the SD card manually.

@Jason : We've considered that, but its not a comprehensive solution.  Writing additional code to get 60% of the way to a solution isn't practical - and it also increases the surface area on the code for testing.   The files that need to be shared or offloaded later are also not limited to logs, but include a database and images.   I fail to understand why Google needs to "police" apps that want to store their own data in a location of their choosing.  If we are ok with it being accessible  why should they care? end of rant!

To be clear: We could have the users upload logs, their database and or other diagnostic images, but they are often in areas that are offline.  We could have the app copy the necessary data to, say ~/Documents to make them accessible (but then... why not just allow the app to store them there in the first place?! ) {{{TILT}}}.
I suppose the answer is "there ISN'T a solution" except to write additional code to get around Google's irrational restrictions?

@CommonsWare : The app is installed on Samsung Tabs configured by the IT department.  It is NOT proprietary firmware, however.

For the time being, I've implemented a "backup" option that makes a copy of all the app data (database, images, logs, configurations, etc) to the Documents folder.  This will allow us and the field engineers to pull files for inspection as needed.   What's odd, is that the app can do this, but if a new version of the app is installed, it is unable to READ (nor WRITE) data created in the Documents folder by a prior version of the app.   A bit strange.

but if a new version of the app is installed, it is unable to READ (nor WRITE) data created in the Documents folder by a prior version of the app. Is there any error log?

@Jianwei Sun : The only error received in these cases are an "access denied" error.  There is nothing else of relevance in any logs or debug traces.  I'll double check.  Is this expected behavior?

About "access denied" error, you can add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to your AndroidMainfest.xml

@JianweiSun-MSFT: I have this in the manifest already, but it does not work.

Hi @DAConsulting, have you added the runtime permission for your code?

@JessieZhang-MSFT : I'm not sure how that would be done.  Aren't the manifest entries sufficient by themselves?

You can check the official document first: Permissions. And there is a sample included in this document, you can check it.
